# Xcode & preprocessor ##

Tags: xcode, preprocessor

In Xcode can I use ## in a macro?

In MSVC I can write:

```
#define FOO(_var) int foo##_var## = 1

    FOO(bar);
    foobar++;
```

On the Mac (**edit:** compiling with GCC) the same code gives me the error "Pasting "foobar" and "=" does not give a valid preprocessing token. Is ## not supported in xcode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Concatenation is supported in GCC and Clang.  Xcode isn't a compiler; if you're posting errors like this, check what version of GCC, LLVM-GCC or Clang ("LLVM compiler") you're using because their behavior can differ.

You're trying to make `=` part of an identifier (i.e., create a variable called `foobar=`) which I don't think is what you want.

Try `#define FOO(_var) int foo##_var = 1` instead.

Incidentally, Clang gives a somewhat better error message:

```
foo.c:4:5: error: pasting formed 'foobar=', an invalid preprocessing token
    FOO(bar);
    ^
foo.c:1:32: note: instantiated from:
#define FOO(_var) int foo##_var## = 1
                               ^
```

Comment: That did it, I had extra ## which compiled fine in MSVC but not under GCC. Thanks Nicholas.